# Center div on screen that has been rotated and scaled with css3

Tags: html, css

I have the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/quacu0hv/

I cant figure out how to center this div. The fact that it is rotated makes it hard to actually center the object on screen. How exactly can this be achieved with pure css? I imagine its due to the point of origin that changed its position (upper left vertex of the div).

```
div {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 1 !important;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try rearranging the `transform` values and see what happens ;)

Turns out order does matter. If you think about it, it does makes sense:

**Rotate > Scale > Translate**

Once you've rotated it, the origin has been rotated too. That's why your square moves "left" and "up" from the origin.

---

**Translate > Rotate > Scale**

This is what you want to do. Position before you make any other adjustments that can affect the origin.

Comment: Thank you @luke .
Re-ordering *Translate > Rotate > Scale*  Solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS [`transform-origin: 50% 50%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) or try `0 0`. <del>Remove `position: absolute` first.</del>

This is at [`0 0`](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/1vxh5w7c/)

This is at [`50% 50%`](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/ujpwdf85/1/)

> This is at [`45% -290%`](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/kqduqtm4/) Centered?

Yeah, looks centered to me, see Full Page. Anyways, as you can see from the other answers `transform-origin` is the best solution. Scott suggested to remove the `transform: -50% -50%` which makes perfect sense if you wanted the div centered in the first place, but if you wanted that in there still and have it centered as a square in a rectangle (height is smaller than width), then 45% by -290%.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.center {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 45% -290%;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='center'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about changing the order of the transform by putting the translate first? I mean the entire thing is calculated by vector multiplication where the order matters. Is using transform-origin a better solution?

Comment: Idk, all I know is that's what it's purpose is for. This isn't an animation, so I suppose order doesn't matter just the results or where and how your div ends up.

Comment: OIC you rotate then scale will be different than scale then rotate, ok well I'm not sure what it would be looking like once centered.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove `translate(50%, 50%);`

```css
div {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(2);
  opacity: 1 !important;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quacu0hv/4/)

or add `transform-origin: 0 0;` to start transformations in the upper left corner.

```css
div {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quacu0hv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Using transform-origin you can get the result, also scale and rotate goes before positioning.

```css
div {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(2) translate(-50%, 50%);
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/quacu0hv/8/