# progress bar CSS problem with MediaElements.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, mediaelement.js

I designed my own styles for *MediaElements.js* and everything works fine but the progress bar.

I want to show the progress as a filled background but can't get it aligned to the left. Despite whatever styles I try to apply, the result shows the progress bar centered:

[image]

This happens to `time-current` and also to `time-loaded` elements. They should be both aligned left after the play/pause button. Internally it is done by `transform: scaleX()` which seems to be related to the problem.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/gfm7b80t/).

Comment: Add `transform-origin: 0 0;` to the time-current span.

Comment: Chrises answer is correct

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, that works! if yo convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @geraldo It's basically a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172022/center-div-on-screen-that-has-been-rotated-and-scaled-with-css3 (and won't be useful to anyone else, the reason why I posted the answer as comment)